# jquery create problems

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$base_url}resources/themes/{$set_theme}/css/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$base_url}resources/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$base_url}resources/javascript/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>

<form action="{$base_url}{$fil_index_register}" id="register" method="post" autocomplete="off">
date of brith:<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="cal" value="" class="" id="ds" >
<input type="button" name="button" onclick="javascript:$('register').submit();" value="ACCOUNT_040" class="button" />

</form>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
        {literal}

        $(function(){
            $( "#ds" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });

        });

        {/literal}
    </script>
```

problem:-when i include js script script submit button is not working but js of calender is working and when remove js script submit button starts works.please help me.i am implementing this on pixaria software

Comment: thank for answer but it not working.it's work fine when comment 2nd and 3rd lines it works fine but required script not work(dat is ovious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "$"  create the problem so i avoid "$" i used

```
onclick="javascript:document.forms['register'].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call:

```
$('#register').submit();
```

You have forgot about # (select for element's ID)

Answer (score 0):

so, you mean that the submit button is not working??
well, here's the solution:

change the:

```
$('register')
```

to:

```
$('#register')
```

'#' symbol is identifier for id
'.' symbol is for class
and no symbol is for HTML tags

Hope this works